# Compound distribution of Uniform and Exponential

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to take the compound distribution of a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, \frac{t}{2})$ where $t$ is parameterized by the exponential distribution $\varepsilon (\lambda)$.

Taking the compound distribution I believe gives the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac 2 t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \, dt$$

I am not able to evaluate this integral. Have I made a mistake in my reasoning anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question looks as if it might mean the following. You have a random variable $T$ whose distribution is $e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda\,dt)$ for $t\ge0$ (and note how I distinguish between the meanings of capital $T$ and lower-case $t$) and another random variable --- let us call it $X$ --- whose distribution is uniform between $0$ and $T/2.$ You want to "take the compound distribution", which I'm guessing may mean you want to find the marginal distribution of $X.$ But the integral you've written is just a number; it does not identify any distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: $($Actually the value of the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac 2 t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \, dt$ is $+\infty.) \qquad$

Comment: Is my first comment what your question is intended to mean?

Comment: Yes your first comment is what I was struggling to say. Thanks for the clarification on the proper notation and terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that:
$$P(X<x \mid  T = t) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{2}{t}ds & \text{if } x<\displaystyle\frac{t}{2}\\
0 & \text{if } x>\displaystyle\frac{t}{2}\\
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{2x}{t} & \text{if } x<\displaystyle\frac{t}{2}\\
0 & \text{if } x>\displaystyle\frac{t}{2}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then, using the law of total probability, we get that:

$$P(X<x) = \int_0^{+\infty}P(X<x \mid T = t) f_T(t) \, dt,$$

where $f_T(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ is the pdf of $T$. The previous integral is rewritten as follows:

$$P(X<x) = \int_{2x}^{+\infty} \frac{2x}{t} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \, dt.$$

Unfortunately, the last integral can't be solved using known functions. Moreover, as pointed out by Michael Hardy, I'm not sure that it converges.

Comment: The integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \Pr(X<x\mid T=t) f_T(t) \, dt$ has to converge. However, you need to say $\Pr(X<x \mid T=t) = 1$ if $x>t/2. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Why do we need to say that $P(X<x \mid T = t) = 1$ if $x > t/2$?

Comment: Because $X$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,\,t/2],$ so $\Pr(X\le t/2) = 1. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy ok, this is true for $x \leq t/2$, not for $x > t/2$, right?

Comment: If $0\le x\le t/2$ then $\Pr(X < x) = 2x/t.$ But if $x>t/2$ then $\Pr(X < x) = 1. \qquad$

Comment: Suppose $X\sim \operatorname{Uniform}[0,t/2].$ Then $$ \Pr(X<x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x\le 0, \\ \\ 2x/t & \text{if } 0\le x\le t/2, \\ \\ 1 & \text{if } x\ge t/2. \end{cases} $$